# Why does the root variable eventually keep the result of the whole tree which is made inside the while loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

curr variable has a reference to root in the first iteration of while loop, but starting from the second iteration curr variable should have a reference to a newly created node every iteration?

```js
var TreeNode = function (value, left, right) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
};

function arrayToTree(array) {
    if (!array.length) return undefined;
    var root = new TreeNode(array.shift());
    var queue = [root];

    while (array.length) {
        var curr = queue.shift();
        var left = new TreeNode(array.shift());
        curr.left = left;
        queue.push(left);
        if (!array.length) break;
        var right = new TreeNode(array.shift());
        queue.push(right);
        curr.right = right;
    }

    return root;
};

const ret = arrayToTree([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root` variable just references the root object. That doesn't change during the process of extension. But during that process, the `left` and `right` properties of that object change value (from `null` to a new node).

In the first iteration of the loop, `curr` gets to reference the same object as `root`, and so whatever mutation is brought to `curr` is brought to `root`: both variables are giving access to the *same* single object. As the code sets `curr.left` to a new node and sets `curr.right` to a new node, at that moment `root.left` and `root.right` have been set to new nodes.

In the next iteration, `curr` will reference one of those newly created nodes (which are already "attached" to `root`), and the same happens there: as `curr` is mutated, we actually mutate a node that can be reached from `root`. That deeper node gets extended with new nodes referenced by its `left` and/or `right` properties.

Comment: "In the next iteration, curr will reference one of those newly created nodes (which are already "attached" to root)..."
It was confusing how the newly created node becomes attached to root. So the newly created node is becoming the property of the root, that's why it all works.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think trincot answered your question.  If that isn't clear, please comment.

But if you want a version of this that involves no mutation, you can do it recursively, by noting that the left child of the node formed from the value at index `i` is the one formed from the value at index `2 * i + 1` and the right child from the value at index `2 * i + 2`, assuming they exist:

```js
const toTree = (xs, i = 0) =>
  i >= xs .length
    ? undefined
    : {value: xs [i], left: toTree (xs, 2 * i + 1), right: toTree (xs, 2 * i + 2)}

console .log (toTree ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This does not use your TreeNode constructor.  Unless there's more to it than is shown, I see no reason for it.  But if we need to use it, we could replace this:

```js
    : {value: xs [i], left: toTree (xs, 2 * i + 1), right: toTree (xs, 2 * i + 2)}
```

with this:

```js
    : new TreeNode (xs [i], toTree (xs, 2 * i + 1), toTree (xs, 2 * i + 2))
```